# Is scrapy.conf safe to use?

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, pymongo

I was following [a tutorial on implementing MongoDB on Scrapy](https://realpython.com/blog/python/web-scraping-with-scrapy-and-mongodb/), and I saw it uses `from scrapy.conf import settings` to access the settings. However, I see no mention of `scrapy.conf` in the [most recent documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html), but it can only be seen in [documentation for the obsolete version](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.12/topics/settings.html).

I just tried it out for my own codes, and it seems like it works fine, but I was just wondering if there is any catch in using now seemingly obsolete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scrapy.conf` is [deprecated](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/75cd056223a5a8da87a361aee42a541afcf27553/scrapy/conf.py) since Scrapy 0.25. If you would import it, you should get a warning:

> Module `scrapy.conf` is deprecated, use `crawler.settings` attribute instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem with obsolete code is exactly that, it is obsolete and it is very likely to be removed on the following versions.

You can access the settings directly from the spider with `self.crawler.settings`